# Send list on image in json

Tags: mysql, json, blob

I have a user table(MySQL) in which I stored user details and Only one profile Image.I want to show all the image on the admin User Management page.I am able to send User details in JSON Object, but not Image column (BLOB).

Is there any way so that I can show the Image as well with user details??
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: can you show your table and some of your try?

Comment: You could send the data in your JSON response using a base64 encoded data url. With respect to caching  it would be a better idea to send an URL that can be used to request this image.

Comment: My User Table: 
username     | first_name     | Last_Name  | UserImage  | Pwd
---------------- |------------------|---------------- |--------------- |-------
Varchar(225)| Varchar(225)| Varchar(225)| BLOB         | Varchar(225)

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Store the image in a file, then use

```
<img src=filename.jpg>
```

Plan B:  Encode the image in Base64, then use

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA7Q1...">
```

Plan A is better for larger images.  Plan B *might* be faster for thumbnails, especially if the client (the admin, in your case) is likely to be 'far' from the server.

As far as JSON goes, well that is just a way to transfer the data.  You can put `filename.jpg` or `/9j/...` in an array in JSON for your Javascript to parse and build the `<img>` tags from.